# python chromedirver won't quit

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

[I am not good at English. Please understand. :
) ]

Sometimes even though using implicate timeout, chrome driver does not end.

To prevent this, I'm using the Timeout Decorator for Windows.

The timeout decorator works well,

But then, the Chrome driver not be shut down.

I also checked if it was the same object, but the object was the same.

What's the reason?

It seems to be using the timeout decorator...(the Chrome driver is also the latest version.)

self.driver.quit() <---- There is a problem with this method.

```
@timeout(10)
def driver_quit(self):
    self.driver.quit()

@timeout(120)
def driver_get(self, url):
    self.driver.get(url)


def call_url(self, url):
    try:
        self.driver_get(url)
    except Exception as e:
        try:
            self.driver_quit()
        except Exception as e:
            pass



def timeout(timeout):
    from threading import Thread
    import functools


    def deco(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            res = [Exception('function [%s] timeout [%s seconds] exceeded!' % (func.__name__, timeout))]
        def newFunc():
            try:
                res[0] = func(*args, **kwargs)
            except Exception as e:
                res[0] = e

        t = Thread(target=newFunc)
        t.daemon = True
        try:
            t.start()
            t.join(timeout)
        except Exception as je:
            print('error starting thread')
            raise je
        ret = res[0]
        if isinstance(ret, BaseException):
            raise ret
        return ret

    return wrapper

return deco
```

=============== Modified code ===============

WebDriverException occurs on finally,

but Chamedriver shut down this line ==> driver.close().

```
def call_url(self, url):
    try:
        self.driver_get(url)
    except:
         try:
             self.driver_quit()
         except:
             pass
         finally:
             self.driver.close()
             self.driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But it still doesn't end.

Comment: Where have you added the `finally` in the code?

Comment: what version of chromedriver are you using?

Comment: Did you try my work around? If it doesn't work please let me know...

Comment: Thank you very much. I couldn't confirm your answer because I had something to do yesterday. Thanks to your advice, I solved it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad to help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround is to call both `driver.quit()` and `driver.close()`.

To do so you can put the commands in a `finally:` statement.

You will wrap all your automation with a `try:` and `except:` then use the `finally:` statement at the end.

```
try:
    # do my automated tasks
except:
    pass
finally:
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
```

**EDIT**

If you find this does not help you just report a bug to selenium and the webdriver maintainers.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg try it your self... it works great for me... If I don't use this my RAM is loaded...

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg regarding the error... it does not throw one because the `close()` method just closes the browser not the process session while the `quit()` method kills the process too...

Comment: report a bug to selenium and the webdriver maintainers if driver.quit() does not kill the driver and all windows

Comment: it has happened before... https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1135

Comment: sure.. and it's been fixed

Comment: "known issue" != "old fixed bug"

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg done... thanks for the input and your time!

Comment: Thank you very much. I couldn't confirm your answer because I had something to do yesterday. Thanks to your advice, I solved it. Thank you very much.

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg Recently, this design has stopped working for me. I didn't change anything in the code, just updated the chrome driver. Don't know what could be the matter? Before that, for several years, the driver was closed in 100% of cases, now it is always different.